# Memory leak when close pipline on the jetson nx

Tags: c++

**Describe**
I use GStreamer to decode H264 streams,When there is a break in decoding(e.g:network problems or RTSP streams shutdown...),i will close this pipline(pipline status:PLAYING->NULL) and try to reconnect,but memory leaks.

**Setup**

- NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX -Jetpack 4.4[L4T 32.4.3] and Jetpack 4.6
- GStreamer 1.14.5

**pipline**

- "rtspsrc location=" + (rtsp address) + " ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=(string)BGRx !  videoconvert ! appsink name=autovideosink"
- "rtspsrc location=" + (rtsp address) + " ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=(string)BGRx !  videoconvert ! appsink name=autovideosink"

**test code**

- Test code referenced from https://github.com/olibartfast/object-detection-inference ,The pipeline setup is as follows:

  ```
      sink_ = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline_), "autovideosink");

      gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals((GstAppSink*)sink_, true);  

      gst_app_sink_set_drop((GstAppSink*)sink_, true);  

      gst_app_sink_set_max_buffers((GstAppSink*)sink_, 1);  

      static GstAppSinkCallbacks callbacks_ = { NULL, new_preroll, new_sample };  

      gst_app_sink_set_callbacks (GST_APP_SINK(sink_), &callbacks_, NULL, NULL);
  ```
- I use valgrind and view jtop tools discovered memory leak.some logs:

```
==25957== 58 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 27 of 95  
==25957==    at 0x48450F8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)  
==25957==    by 0x401300B: _dl_exception_create (dl-exception.c:77)  
==25957==    by 0x527AADB: _dl_signal_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:117)  
==25957==    by 0x400828B: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2384)  
==25957==    by 0x401173F: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:235)  
==25957==    by 0x527AB6B: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)  
==25957==    by 0x40112D7: _dl_open (dl-open.c:605)  
==25957==    by 0x5397013: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:66)  
==25957==    by 0x527AB6B: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)  
==25957==    by 0x527AC0F: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:215)  
==25957==    by 0x5398777: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:162)  
==25957==    by 0x53970E7: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.17 (dlopen.c:87)  
  
==25957== 24,857 (24,798 direct, 59 indirect) bytes in 43 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 89 of 95  
==25957==    at 0x48450F8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)  
==25957==    by 0x4A6C57F: g_malloc (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)  
  
==25957== LEAK SUMMARY:  
==25957==    definitely lost: 24,856 bytes in 44 blocks  
==25957==    indirectly lost: 59 bytes in 1 blocks  
==25957==      possibly lost: 6,532 bytes in 71 blocks  
==25957==    still reachable: 2,246,215 bytes in 29,650 blocks  
==25957==                       of which reachable via heuristic:  
==25957==                         length64           : 3,152 bytes in 68 blocks  
==25957==                         newarray           : 1,936 bytes in 41 blocks  
==25957==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==25957==   
==25957== ERROR SUMMARY: 16944812 errors from 102 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)  
==25957==   
==25957== 1 errors in context 1 of 102:  
==25957== Thread 18 omxh264dec-omxh2:  
==25957== Use of uninitialised value of size 8  
==25957==    at 0x765FFE8: NvBufferSetFdMapping (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvbuf_fdmap.so.1.0.0)  
==25957==    by 0x75A7C1F: ExtractFdFromNvBuffer (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvbuf_utils.so.1.0.0)  
==25957==    by 0x754A9D3: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstomx.so)  
==25957==    by 0x48CEFF7: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.1405.0)  
==25957==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation  
==25957==    at 0x48450F8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)  
==25957==    by 0x7DA9EEF: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvomx.so)  
==25957==    by 0x754228F: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstomx.so)  
==25957==    by 0x75422D7: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstomx.so)  
==25957==    by 0x754BE6B: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstomx.so)  
==25957==    by 0x754DDBF: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstomx.so)  
==25957==    by 0x4942EB3: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.1405.0)  
==25957==   
==25957==   
==25957== 1 errors in context 2 of 102:  
==25957== Thread 13 rtpjitterbuffer0:  
==25957== Invalid read of size 4  
==25957==    at 0x4903958: gst_mini_object_unref (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.1405.0)  
==25957==  Address 0x8538608 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 72 free'd  
==25957==    at 0x4846360: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:540)  
==25957==    by 0x7552093: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstomx.so)  
==25957==    by 0x720316F: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0.1405.0)  
==25957==  Block was alloc'd at  
==25957==    at 0x48450F8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)  
==25957==    by 0x4A6C57F: g_malloc (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)  
==25957==   
==25957==   
==25957== 1 errors in context 3 of 102:  
==25957== Invalid read of size 4  
==25957==    at 0x4934F6C: gst_structure_copy (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.1405.0)  
==25957==  Address 0x8538908 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd  
==25957==    at 0x4846360: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:540)  
==25957==    by 0x4A367A7: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)  
==25957==  Block was alloc'd at  
==25957==    at 0x48450F8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)  
==25957==    by 0x4A6C57F: g_malloc (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
```

**test script**

- valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes --error-limit=no --log-file=memchk.log -v ./object-detection-inference --link="rtsp://..."

i don't know how to upload my test code

Answer (score 0):

you should start to test your gstreamer pipeline alone using gst-launch-1.0, if it works the problem could be in my code, I never tested with jetson

Comment: Thank you for your replies,I'll run the test like you said.